# "this" inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript

This is a newbie query. I went through few similar posts, but they are not helping me enough. This post has 2 queries, but am putting together because their root seems the same.

I came across the following code snippet :

```
var Server = module.exports.Server = function Server(listener) {
  if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(listener);
  //other code
}

module.exports.createServer = function(listener) {
  return new Server(listener);
};
```

I am unable to understand the use of  `if (!(this instanceof Server))  ;` when can this not point to Server here ?

I tried putting a quick test for this :

```
var createTest = function(){
    console.log(this.toString());
    return new Test();
};

var Test = function Test(){
    console.log(this instanceof Test);
    console.log(this.toString());
    if (!(this instanceof Test)) 
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}

var tester = createTest();
```

which outputs :

```
[object global]
true
[object Object]
```

which further confuses me over why this.toString prints [object Object] - shouldn't it be [object Test] ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps it's because you're in the constructor, and therefore the class is not yet considered a `Test` object? Just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an idiom used to make `new` optional. For example:

```
function TraditionalTest() {
}
function IdiomaticTest() {
    if(!(this instanceof IdiomaticTest)) return new IdiomaticTest();
}

console.log(new TraditionalTest());  // [object Object]
console.log(TraditionalTest());      // undefined
console.log(new IdiomaticTest());    // [object Object]
console.log(IdiomaticTest());        // [object Object]
```

---

As for why it's `[object Object]` rather than `[object Test]`, I don't know why it's defined that way, but [that's the way it's defined](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2):

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return "`[object Undefined]`".
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return "`[object Null]`".
> 3. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let *class* be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *O*.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings "`[object`", *class*, and "`]`".

[[Class]] is referenced several times in the specification, but it only ever represents built-in types:

- `Arguments`
- `Array`
- `Boolean`
- `Date`
- `Error`
- `Function`
- `JSON`
- `Math`
- `Number`
- `Object`
- `RegExp`
- `String`

Comment: Can you please explain the second part of my query too ?

Comment: +1 Where ES5 uses a word in `[[]]` (like `[[Prototype]]`) it means it's a specification mechanism. Implementations must behave as if they support it, but don't actually have to have it. So `[[Class]]` is just a way to define classes of objects without specifying that they actually have an internal, inaccessible *Class* attribute. They just have to behave as if they do. See [ES5 §8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2)

Answer (score 1):

That test makes sure that a new server instanced is created for both of these uses:

```
new module.exports.Server()
```

and for:

```
module.exports.Server()
```

In the second one, the `this` pointer would be the global object and thus would not be an instanceof Test.  In that case, the code realizes that the constructor function was just called directly without `new` so no new object was created.  Since that is not the intended use of the constructor, it forces a `new` to be used by invoking one and returning the result.

Comment: For the second part, how is console.log(this instanceof Test); returning true then ?

Comment: You are invoking it with `return new Test();` which creates a new `Test` object and then calls the constructor with `this` set to that new object.  So `console.log(this instanceof Test);` inside the constructor shows that this is indeed happening.